# Representations of signed areas

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am studying differential forms and have difficulty with the following question：Suppose $v_1,v_2$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $S$ is the triangle spanned by $v_1,v_2$ and $S_1$ is the projection of $S$ onto the plane $x_1Ox_2$.Then how to use $v_1,v_2$ to represent the signed area of $S_1$? And this induces a 2-form.

Comment: You might find some of my YouTube videos (linked in my profile) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

(Signed) area of $S_1$ $=dx_1\wedge dx_2(v_1,v_2)$